Why are these allium (ornamental onion) cells green?
Can you help tell me why these three images of allium (ornamental onion) slides are appearing as green, even though there is no chloroplast in onions? Thank you.




Welcome Tomma. This doesn't appear to be a species ID question so I've submitted an edit to remove the tag. Tell us, where did you get the pictures, did you take them? How had the samples been prepared? Had any stain been used (Aldehyde Fuchsin, Alcian Blue, Movat's Pentachrome Stain for example)?

Also - have you adjusted the white balance on your camera? what sort of optical set-up are you using?

Just to clarify, you should [edit] the question with the additional information requested.

I would bet strongly it is the by product of the stains or fixative agents used in slide preparation.  A type of stain called malachite green is sometimes used to stain cellulose and lignin in plant cell walls, and to make cell structures more visible by creating contrast.  In some concentrations, it can even take on a bluish-green color.  Fast green is used in a similar fashion.  Without knowing the exact staining protocol used, it's impossible to know for certain, but one of these is my best bet for the reason why your cells appear greenish.
